# Why does TableView doesn't display the JSON array?

Tags: java, json, javafx, tableview

I'm fetching a array of objects from an HTTP request and trying to display that same data onto a TableView. I'm new to JavaFX and only using it for school projects.
I've read tutorials on the Web and similar questions on SO, but nothing really helped.

I guess I'm doing wrong with "mapping" the columns to the property of the objects inside the array, but that's just speculation, nothing for certain.

Here is the JSON array of objects:

```
[{"id":2,"nome":"Etapa 2","pcc":false},{"id":3,"nome":"Etapa 3","pcc":false},{"id":4,"nome":"Etapa 4","pcc":false},{"id":5,"nome":"Etapa 5","pcc":false},{"id":6,"nome":"Etapa 6","pcc":false},{"id":7,"nome":"Etapa 7","pcc":false},{"id":1,"nome":"Etapa 1","pcc":true}]
```

Here is the class of the objects I'm receiving:

```
package pt.ipvc.haccp.entity;

public class Etapa {

public Etapa(int id, String nome, boolean pcc) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.pcc = pcc;
}

private int id;

private String nome;

private boolean pcc;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public boolean isPcc() {
    return pcc;
}

public void setPcc(boolean pcc) {
    this.pcc = pcc;
}
```

}

And here is the controller class

```
package pt.ipvc.haccp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import pt.ipvc.haccp.entity.Etapa;

public class GestaoEtapasController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView<?> tableEtapas;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Etapa, String> id;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Etapa, String> nome;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Etapa, String> pcc;

@FXML
private TableView<?> tableRiscos;

@FXML
private TableView<?> tableMedidas;


public GestaoEtapasController() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.preencherEtapas();
    
}




private void preencherEtapas() {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/haccp/rest/etapa")).build();
    try {
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response.body());
        
        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Etapa, String>("id"));
        nome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Etapa, String>("nome"));
        
        ObservableList<JSONArray> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr);
        tableEtapas.setItems(data); // This throws an error: The method setItems(ObservableList<capture#1-of ?>) in the type TableView<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (ObservableList<JSONArray>)

        
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao obter as etapas");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm new to JavaFX (but not to Java in general) so I belive I'm just missing the workflow of JavaFX itself. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Typo

Comment: You need to define the type for the TableView, do not use wildcard. `private TableView<Etapa> tableEtapas;` and your ObservableList should be `ObservableList<Etapa> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr);` so convert JSONArray to List<Etapa>.  Also I suggest using Property wrappers for your Object fields, like (StringProperty nome, BooleanProperty pcc) to make things easier in the future

Comment: I managed to fix it in a different way by just changing the directory of class Etapa to the same location as the Controller. It's weird, but it fixed.
Nice catch on the StringProperty, I'll check on that. Thanks